# Mix hangs on deps.compile while compiling riak_core project

Tags: elixir, elixir-mix, rebar3

I am trying to compile https://github.com/kanatohodets/elixir_riak_core_ping. I have erlang 18 installed and elixir version is 1.3.

compilation hangs at below line and does not move ahead:

```
Downloaded package, caching at /Users/navinnegi/.cache/rebar3/hex/default/packages/pc-1.4.0.tar
```

[image]

if I stop and try to run deps.compile again, it stops at line

```
Compiling parse_trans
```

[image]

However if I delete rebar3 folder located at User/username/.cache, and run deps.compile. compilation is stuck on below line again

Downloaded package, caching at /Users/navinnegi/.cache/rebar3/hex/default/packages/pc-1.4.0.tar

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, this was entirely my fault, I started with riak_core using "Little riak core book" and added rebar3 in my path as suggested in the book, this was causing the issue/conflict between mix and rebar3.

After removing rebar3 from PATH, every thing compiles fine.